# C# How to make an in memory object (DataTable) accessible from other applications, asp websites

Tags: c#

I basically have a page which needs to have a specific set of data available to it, I also need this data accessible from other applications.  SQL is to slow for this, so my first thought is to have a Datatable already populated and use linq to select from it.

How can I have 1 executable house a datatable that I can then access from other applications?  Also - is a Datatable the best structure for my data?  The data is basically 400k rows by 6 columns.

Comment: What about caching?

Comment: @Shaharyar everything is on the table, I honestly am not 100% sure what i'm looking for i thought about in memory file but that has it's drawbacks

Comment: Actually I am not so sure about how good or bad is accessing an in memory object is. But when you have a scenario like RDBMS is too slow and you want to select some repetitive data very fast, you build a caching layer in between code and DB like Redis etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another (better, I believe) approach is to employ `MarshalByRefObject`. This way you could pass the object - actually proxies to the object - between `AppDomain`s so you don't need serialization at all.

Check out [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx) on the subject

And this is live example I developed couple of years ago, with different goal in mind though. It's a custom web server, which needed to update it self whenever update is available, without interrupting its jobs. So shadow copying was the goal, but I think it is (more) appropriate to use `MarshalByRef` objects in your scenario.

```
    public void Boot()
    {
        if (KernelPartition != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Kernel partition already exists.");
        }

        Log.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, "Initiating startup sequence...");
        KernelPartition = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Kernel", null, new AppDomainSetup() { ApplicationName = "krnl", ShadowCopyFiles = "true" });
        KernelPartition.DomainUnload += KernelPartition_DomainUnload;

        string engineClassName = null;
        string engineAssemblyName = null;

        try
        {
            var engineTypeId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["engineTypeId"];
            engineClassName = engineTypeId.Split(',')[0].Trim();
            engineAssemblyName = engineTypeId.Substring(engineClassName.Length + 1).Trim();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Log.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, "Configuration errors detected. Attempting defaults...");
            engineClassName = "Contoso.Kernel.Turbine";
            engineAssemblyName = "Contoso.Kernel";
        }

        try
        {
            // FOCUS ON THE NEXT LINE
            KernelTurbine = (ITcsKernel)KernelPartition.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(engineAssemblyName, engineClassName);
            Log.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, "Kernel connection established.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, "Failed to establish communication channel with the kernel with the following exception:\n{0}", ex.ToString());
        }

        if (KernelTurbine == null)
        {
            InitializeRestart();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Start();
                Log.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, "Startup sequence completed.");
                KernelTurbine.RebootDelegate = Reboot;
                DisposeRestartSecond();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = string.Format("The startup sequence failed with the following exception:{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, ex.ToString());
                Log.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0, message);

                InitializeRestart();
            }
        }
    }
```

As I remember, you create the object in the other `AppDomain` by `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()`. This object needs to inherit `MarshalByRefObject`. So compose a class which inherits it and internally use `DataTable`.

I hope you can handle it from here. I really can't remember the details but I'm ready to help further should you need.

Comment: Thanks again Bozhidar - this one is really tough to find an example of

Comment: Maybe what i;m trying to do just isn't possible.  I want 1 application to hold everything in memory and then query that object that only returns 'x'.  The problem is SQL is just too slow

Comment: Bozhidar - let me work on this for a bit.  I;ll follow up :)

Comment: @JoshuaLong - of course it is possible. This does exactly what you're after :). I believe this is the way - work through it and see what happens. It is not a trivial task but definitely possible! If not already, gain some knowledge on `AppDomains`. This is your starting point.

Comment: Bozhidar - I find a pertty decent example of a TCP interface that is a ton of less code - i'm going to make another posting and i'll link it here

Comment: @JL1 - glad you made your mind. Just know that this is a copy-paste from a program I wrote once - it contains unrelated to marshaling stuff. Just focus on the line I pointed by comment...

Comment: Bozhidar i'm going to make this the answer not so much for the code but for MarshalByRefObject.  Here is the follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778854/c-sharp-how-to-pass-linq-in-an-interface-marshalbyrefobject

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles` is what you're looking for.
You can initialize your data table and serialize it using `WriteXml()`.
Then map that file to memory by calling `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.CreateFromFile()` method.

Then you could access the file from multiple processes and do stuff with it.
E.g. you can resemble the data table in another process by calling `ReadXml()`
You can find more info about `MemoryMappedFiles` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

- This is doable in .NET 4.0 and on!

Comment: Bozhidar - I thought about this why do I care about WriteXML()?

Comment: Also isn't the kind of redundant?  So I create a datatable, then I create an xml file, then I save the xml file serializing my class then I read the xml file back to a datatable... every time?

Comment: @JoshuaLong - I can't imagine how else you can access the data table. Its called `MemoryMappedFiles` - so you need to serialize your data somehow in order to become a file. `WriteXml()` and `ReadXml()` are working out of the box. But you could implement binary serialization to gain more speed...

Comment: Bozhidar - I think I going to pass on this.  This method would require me loading the entire collection of a million objects everytime i wanted to use it once.  Thanks though1